SPSS mixed effect moderation output
in my conceptul model I want to study if Extroversion trait (Extro IV: likert scale) effects initial offer in a negotiation (Offer DV: any number between 5 and 15), and how does trust moderate this relationship (Time: no trust=1, trust=2)
I used the mixed effects model in SPSS as my data is within subjects, where each respondent was asked to input an offer in a 'no trust' scenario, and later also in a 'trust' scenario (repeated measures). I also included Neuroticis, Openness, Agreeableness, Conscientiousness, and Gender as covariates.
As fixed effects I included all covariates and Extroversion, as well as the interaction between Time and Extroversion (I assumed this reflects the moderation, correct?)
I got the following output:Can someone help me interpreting the output to answer my research question? I am not sure where to look for significance in this case.

Significance is in the column marked "sig." and you can look for the two effects you mention in the rows with those names. You should look at other things as well, like the size of the parameter estimates and their standard errors, and you may want to make some tables or graphs of the model.
You many also want to think about your model more generally. You say your DV takes on any value from 0 to 15 but do you mean any real value or any integer? And, in the latter case, what values does it actually take on? If only a few, then you may want to use ordinal logistic regression.
And you may want to consider splines of your IVs, to look for nonlinear relationships.
